# Play framework 2.3.x where do traffic logs get written?

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, web-traffic

I built my play application using

```
activator clean compile dist
```

I then extracted it to a folder and started the application using Play's integrated HTTP server

```
sudo ./appname -Dhttp.port=80
```

I then loaded it on localhost:80 and clicked around in it. My question is, where do the traffic logs from my session get written? Not the application logs, but the actual web traffic logs (like apache HTTP server traffic logs)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think Play logs http requests by default. You will have to use filters to do that. If you are using Scala: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaHttpFilters

Comment: Salem is correct. This doc is also helpful: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.0/ScalaInterceptors Note that these code changes go in the root /app/ directory in a Global.scala file